# Wordpress with LiteSpeed shows 404 when trying to access it by my new domain

Tags: wordpress, digital-ocean, litespeed

I have created an instance of wordpress with open LiteSpeed cache in Digital Ocean droplets, it works fine if I have the IP configured in the Settings/General Site and Wordpress URL, but when I add my dns name, starts popping up 404 everywhere. The screen reads:
404
Not Found
The resource requested could not be found on this server!
Proudly powered by LiteSpeed Web Server
Please be advised that LiteSpeed Technologies Inc. is not a web hosting company and, as such, has no control over content found on this site.

I believe the problem is in this LiteSpeed, which don't seem to be clever enough to figure that there is a new domain configured? Unfortunately restarting the LiteSpeed web server did not help...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to access the OpenLiteSpeed Console, you can find the password for the console in the `.litespeed_password` file in the root's home directory on the server.

You also need to allow your IP address to be able to connect to the console, you can do this simply by executing `ufw allow from <your_home_ip_address>`.

Also documented here: https://docs.litespeedtech.com/Cloud/wordpress/#web-server-control-panel-access

When you're within the Console you can go to "Listeners", here you'll find two listeners, one named "Default" and one named "Defaultssl".

On each listener you have to modify the "Virtual Host Mappings" to use your domain under "Domains" - after this restart OpenLiteSpeed, and it should no longer return a 404 when you access the site via your domain.

Comment: damn! i thought i was gonna have to re-install the whole server. thanks so much!