# Moving Digital Ocean Litespeed server to new droplet

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, digital-ocean, litespeed

I'm currently running a litespeed sever with Wordpress on a digital ocean Ubuntu droplet.

I would like to recreate the server on a different team account.

I shut down the droplet, made a snapshot, and transferred the snapshot to the team account.  When I create the new droplet and start the server I get a 404 page due to the listener settings in the litespeed configuration.

I followed the instructions here to update the listener IP adderess ... I do not yet have a domain associated with the site.  ([Wordpress with LiteSpeed shows 404 when trying to access it by my new domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55227751/wordpress-with-litespeed-shows-404-when-trying-to-access-it-by-my-new-domain))

After restarting litespeed the server loads the wordpress site, but only partially.  For example images do not load.  The pages load very slowly and sometimes don't load at all.

How can I transfer the droplet an reconfigure the server so it works correctly?

Comment: Hi, I guess those statics files maybe 404 due to no domain pointing yet. You can try adding a whildcart `*` to both port 80 and 443 listener and add the domain/IP to your hosts file then see how it goes.

Comment: Thanks Eric ... the listeners already seem to have wildcards.  I just changed with IP address in the domain field for the virtual host associated with the listener

Comment: So did it get resolved?

Comment: @Eric no. Still unsuccessful in moving the droplet.

Comment: I am not familiar about how to you direct message you via Stackoverflow -> Users. Could you join to [LiteSpeed community here](https://golitespeed.slack.com/join/shared_invite/enQtMzE5ODgxMTUyNTgzLWVhZDNhZDNmYWRhZmIwNzUxN2Y2ZDRjZGUwZjFiMDk1ZTNjZDJmMDg5NTcyZjFiZDM4MDY1NjkwYjkzM2E5YmE) and message me(@Eric)? Should be able to solve your problem sooner.